Diamond inheritance only for type checking
I am working on an implementation of geometric algebra's.
Here is a minimized example of what I have:
template<int p,int q,int r>
struct geometric_algebra{
    static const int d=p+q+r, e=1<<d;
    struct multivector {
        multivector operator|(multivector w){/*...*/}
        multivector operator&(multivector w){/*...*/}
        /*...*/
    };

    template<int g> struct graded_vector : multivector {
        template<int h>
        graded_vector<g+h> operator|(graded_vector<h>w) {
            return {multivector::operator|(w)};
        }
        template<int h>
        graded_vector<g+h-d> operator&(graded_vector<h>w) {
            return {multivector::operator&(w)};
        }
        /*...*/
    };
};

As you can see the graded_vector specializes a multivector, but does not reimplement anything.
The primary reason for its existence is to have more strict type checking.
A graded vector corresponds to a certain dimension of geometric object.
And I want to use the type checker as a sanity check on these objects
using pga = geometric_algebra<3,0,1>
using point = pga::graded_vector<1>;
using line = pga::graded_vector<2>;
using plane = pga::graded_vector<3>;
plane a = /*...*/
line l = /*...*/
// the intersection of a plane and line is a point
point z = a & l;
line m = a & l; // this should give a compiler error

In conformal geometric algebra (geometric_algebra<4,1,0>) there is a separate distinction between round and flat objects. I also want this distinction to be type-checked.
If I want to continue my current approach, I would need to add the following classes:
flat_vector and flat_graded_vector.
This introduces two problems:

diamond inheritance - flat_graded_vector inherits multivector twice via graded_vector and flat_vector.
Since the operations are overloaded in both graded_vector and flat_vector, it also needs to be overloaded in flat_graded_vector that implements the type logic of both.

Is there a better way to achieve this?
Using composition rather than inheritance (as in Diamond inheritance (C++)) does not seem to fit as a multivector is more than the product of whether it is graded and whether it is flat.
I also don't think mix-ins work as that would require function overloading, which is not possible if the signature is different. Furthermore, graded<g,flat<mv>> is conceptually the same as flat<graded<g, mv>> but the type checker will not understand that.
MWE:
template<int p,int q,int r>
struct geometric_algebra{
    static const int d=p+q+r, e=1<<d;
    struct multivector {
        int data; //stand-in
        multivector operator|(multivector w){
            return {data | w.data}; //stand-in
        }
        multivector operator&(multivector w){
            return {data & w.data}; //stand-in
        }
        /*...*/
    };

    template<int g> struct graded_vector : multivector {
        template<int h>
        graded_vector<g+h> operator|(graded_vector<h>w) {
            return {multivector::operator|(w)};
        }
        template<int h>
        graded_vector<g+h-d> operator&(graded_vector<h>w) {
            return {multivector::operator&(w)};
        }
        /*...*/
    };
};

using pga = geometric_algebra<3,0,1>;
using multivector = pga::multivector;
using point = pga::graded_vector<1>;
using line = pga::graded_vector<2>;
using plane = pga::graded_vector<3>;
point make_pt(double x,double y,double z){
    return {1}; // stand-in
}

int main() {
    point u = make_pt(0,0,1);
    point v = make_pt(0,1,0);
    point w = make_pt(1,0,0);
    plane a = u | v | w;
    point x = make_pt(0,0,0);
    point y = make_pt(1,1,1);
    line l = x | y;
    point z = a & l;
}


Have you tried C++ concepts? You can specify logical operations on other concepts and types and their properties. E.g. template<class T> concept FlatGraded = Flat<T> && Graded<T>;

@Sebastian, as I understand it, concepts tells something about a type, not values of a type. So if you have classes for points, lines, planes, circles, spheres, ... you can use concepts to mark which ones model flat / graded objects. But the other direction does not seem possible: specify the meaning of flat/grade in terms of how operations affect them and infer the classes and the specialisation relations from that.

You can define template function parameter types in terms of concepts.
(Either directly instead of the type name or as a constraint with requires.)
You can define several template functions with the same name as partial specialization and choose, which one is called by which concepts the parameter types follow.
Concepts can be auto-detected by which operations the types offer, e.g. you could define a concept by whether a type can be intersected with a line or by what type the result of the intersection with a line would be.

For your flat/graded example you could define a single template class deriving from multivector. It has separate template parameters, e.g. bool for each property, or int for dimensions. This way you have different types for each of the properties you want to distinguish. Instead of inheritance to recombine results between different types (and to keep the number of types down) or to specify, which operations work, you use concepts. So concepts can work on types and do not have to work on values of a type. This methodology works of course only for properties, you can deduce at compile-time.

In a slight variation (instead of a list of bools) you could use a constexpr class type as a template parameter of your templated multivector derivative. Now you can do constexpr operations in compile-time in constexpr member and free functions of that template parameter class type.

You might look at boost::unit as inspiration.

The crucial insight that solved the problem for me was that I did not need inheritance, I needed conversion.
Thank you to @Sebastian and @Jarod42 for inspiration
For reference, here is a MWE:
template<int p,int q,int r>
struct geometric_algebra{
    static const int d=p+q+r, e=1<<d;

    struct mvprop {
        bool graded = false;
        int grade = 0;
        bool flat = false;
        constexpr bool operator<=(const mvprop other) const {
            return (graded <= other.graded) && (flat <= other.flat);
        }
        constexpr mvprop operator|(mvprop other) const {
            return {graded && other.graded, grade + other.grade, flat || other.flat};
        }
        constexpr mvprop operator&(mvprop other) const {
            return {graded && other.graded, grade + other.grade - d, flat && other.flat};
        }
    };

    template<mvprop g>
    struct multivector {
        int data; //stand-in
        template<mvprop h>
        multivector<g|h> operator|(multivector<h> w){
            return {data | w.data}; //stand-in
        }
        template<mvprop h>
        multivector<g&h> operator&(multivector<h> w){
            return {data & w.data}; //stand-in
        }
        template<mvprop h> requires (h <= g)
        operator multivector<h>() {return {data};}
        /*...*/
    };
};

using cga = geometric_algebra<4,1,0>;
using mv = cga::multivector<{false, 0, false}>;
using flat = cga::multivector<{false, 0, true}>;
using rpoint = cga::multivector<{true, 1, false}>;
using dipole = cga::multivector<{true, 2, false}>;
using circle = cga::multivector<{true, 3, false}>;
using sphere = cga::multivector<{true, 4, false}>;
using rpoint_inf = cga::multivector<{true, 1, true}>;
using point = cga::multivector<{true, 2, true}>;
using line = cga::multivector<{true, 3, true}>;
using plane = cga::multivector<{true, 4, true}>;

rpoint make_rpt(double x,double y,double z, double r=0){
    return {1}; // stand-in
}
rpoint_inf make_inf() {
    return {1}; // stand-in
}

int main() {
    sphere s1 = make_rpt(0,0,1) | make_rpt(0,1,0) | make_rpt(1,0,0) | make_rpt(1,1,1);
    sphere s2 = make_rpt(1,0,1) | make_rpt(1,1,0) | make_rpt(2,0,0) | make_rpt(2,1,1);
    plane a = make_inf() | make_rpt(0,0,0) | make_rpt(1,0,0) | make_rpt(0,1,0);
    line l = make_inf() | make_rpt(0,0,0) | make_rpt(0,0,1);
    circle c = s1 & s2;
    point r = a & l;
    dipole d = c & a;
}

